# Delayed_job is running immediately, although it's set to run later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

So a few minutes ago I was playing around with delayed_job, trying to get it to schedule an action for 5 minutes from now. But instead, it ran immediately. I checked the date and the time on the Rails server that it's running on, and it's indeed up-to-date and accurate. So I can't figure out why this is happening.

For example, here's what I'm passing to delayed_job:

```
[2] pry(#<PostsController>)> date_time
=> Thu, 08 Jun 2017 14:30:00 UTC +00:00
[3] pry(#<PostsController>)> SchedulePost.delay(run_at: date_time).schedule_post(@post)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
```

And I can see from the `rake jobs:work` console that it starts to run immediately after it gets scheduled.

Any idea why this isn't working properly and is running immediately instead?

Comment: What's the current time? Also, maybe timezone problems (your DJ server is  ahead, or something)

Comment: The time at that moment was 2:26 PM

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if I pull the current date, the time zone is exactly the same too.

Comment: `rake jobs:work` will start working off jobs, I think it may include scheduled jobs.

Comment: @Thanh is there any way to kick off the job worker without having it fire off future schedules as well?

Comment: @LewlSauce you can specify queues to run jobs `QUEUES=mailers,tasks rake jobs:work`, so you just need to add your scheduled jobs into a queue and does not include it when starting jobs.